# Layout_below does not work in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm pretty new to Android development.
I'm using the following RelativeLayout.
I want my txtView1 to be above lstAnswers, but layout_below doesn't work and the views are overlayed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="#ffbad6e6"
                tools:context="com.example.user.myApp.QuestionDetails">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:textColor="#ff0d5e52"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lstAnswers"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtView1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried to set layout_below using @+id, like this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1"
```

but that gave me nothing.
Can anybody explain me how can I set txtView1 above lstAnswers?

Answer (score 5):

Very easy.

Remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from your ListView.
So, `android:layout_below="@id/txtView1"` will be able to do its job.